# repaint() is not working in swing

Tags: java, swing, awt

```
package games;

import java.awt.*;   
import java.awt.event.*;   
import javax.swing.*;    

public class viza extends JPanel implements ActionListener {       

/**   
     *   
     */  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;      
    int x=0, y=200;
    Timer tm =new Timer(5,this);     
    public viza(){    
        tm.start();    
    }    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){    
        g.setColor(Color.red);    
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);    
    }     
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){   
        x=x+1;   
        y=y+1;   
        if(x>300)    
           x=0;      
        if(x<0)   
            x=0;        
        repaint();   //after x and y are changet then I use repaint();
    }     // the frame is created and the new object is added into the frame.
    public static void main(String[] args){     
        viza a=new viza();     
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();     
        frame.setSize(500,500);          
        frame.add(a);      
        frame.setVisible(true);         
    }     
}[1]
```

---

The code is used to draw a filled rectangle on the panel. However when I start the program the object moves but the panel is not repainted. If I try and resize the window while the program is runing it does load properly. As soon as i stop doing that the panel or frame (Not sure) is not repainted anymore. So i end up whith a line.

Comment: And how do you think is ever x going to become less than 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should clear the underlying pane before you re-draw the rectangle in its new position.

To do that, let the `super.paintComponent()` do that for you, since that would be the correct approach to custom painting in any `JComponent`:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){    
    super.paintComponent(g); // let it do the default paint
    g.setColor(Color.red);    
    g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);    
}
```

Also you may want to add a default close operation to your frame (in main method) to exit the program after closing the frame:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Another tip is to set a bigger `timeout` for your Timer, because `5` milliseconds is occurring very fast and your user may not see the movement. Try something bigger than `50` or `100`.

Good Luck.

Comment: As always you are right @AndrewThompson. Will edit the answer.

Comment: *"Will edit the answer."* Nice edit. :)  *"As always you are right .."* LOL! I wish. If I were, I'd be writing down tomorrow's lotto numbers. ;)

Comment: "If I were, I'd be writing down tomorrow's lotto numbers. ;)" LOL! :-D

Comment: Thank you very very much. you are the best :)

Comment: @ReiPano: You're welcome. Generally you can show your appreciation by selecting this answer as the answer to your question by clicking on the green check mark on the left side of my answer.